# First of each element in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get **only** the first word of each element within a 2D array.

I'm new to Javascript so I'm not as conversant with the arrow format of function writing as I wish to be and the following

```
calendar_array = calendar_array.map(outer => outer.map(str => {
   let arr = str.split(' ');
  return arr[0];
  }));
```

works on occassion and on others produces the error code:

> split is not a function

at other times.

I've tried a more familiar format for a function

```
/**
*@customfunction
*@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
*VERSION 1 - Returns ONLY the FIRST WORD in the array element to that array element
*/
function firstWordArray(parameterArray)
{
  calendarArray = parameterArray;
  for (week = calendarArray.length - 1; week >= 0; week--)
  {
    for (day = calendarArray[0].length - 1; day >= 0; day--)
    {
      let firstWord = calendarArray[week][day];
      firstWord = firstWord.split(' ');
      calendarArray[week][day] = firstWord[0];
    }
  }
  return calendarArray;
}
```

but still get the same error.

Is there an alternative way in which I can retrieve/keep ONLY the first word of each element  within a 2D array?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this 2D array? If `split()` is not a function it implies that some of the cells in your 2D array do not contain strings as you seem to expect. You can use `Logger.log(yourArray)` to print the contents of your array if you're unsure. Or if that doesn't give you the expected result you can use `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(yourArray))`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, you are encountering an error with the `split` method, which is most likely due to the fact that it can only accept the ***string*** data type. To further analyze the issue on your end, you can use a [try-catch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to identify the specific cause of the problem. As `split` can only process data of type **String**, you can try converting problematic data into a string type. Below is a sample script with some tweaks:

```
function test() {
  //Dummy 'calendar_array' value
  var calendar_array = [
    ["2023-08-01 Some Event", "2023-08-02 Another Event", "2023-08-03 Yet Another Event"],
    ["2023-08-04 Event 1", 12345, "2023-08-06 Event 3"], //Number instead of string at index [1][1]
    ["2023-08-07 Event 4", "2023-08-08 Event 5", "2023-08-09 Event 6"]
  ];

  var resultArray = calendar_array.map(outer => outer.map(str => {
    //Use 'try-catch' block to view the cause of the 'split' method error.
    try { 
      let arr = str.split(' ');
      return arr[0];
    } catch (e) {
      //Log the error
      console.log(` ${str} caused the error (${e}) as it is a "${typeof str}" type.`);
      //Possible fix by converting the current value to actual 'String' data type
      let arr = str.toString().split(' ');
      return arr[0];
    }
  }));

  Logger.log(resultArray);
}
```

### *Demo*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I cannot know the actual value of `calendar_array`. But, from your error message of `split is not a function`, the value of `str` might not be the string type. In this case, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
calendar_array = calendar_array.map(outer => outer.map(str => {
  let arr = (str instanceof String || typeof str == "string") ? str.split(' ') : [str]; // or let arr = (str instanceof String) ? str.split(' ') : [str]; or let arr = (typeof str == "string") ? str.split(' ') : [str];
  return arr[0];
}));
```

- In this modification, the value of `str` is checked and when it is the string type, the 1st word is retrieved by `split`.
- You can test this as follows.

```js
let calendar_array = [
  ["sample1 sample2", ""],
  ["sample1 sample2", 12345],
  ["sample1 sample2", null],
  ["sample1 sample2", undefined],
  ["sample1 sample2", new Date()],
  ["sample1 sample2", { key: "value" }],
  ["sample1 sample2", true],
];

calendar_array = calendar_array.map(outer => outer.map(str => {
  let arr = (str instanceof String || typeof str == "string") ? str.split(' ') : [str]; // or let arr = (str instanceof String) ? str.split(' ') : [str]; or let arr = (typeof str == "string") ? str.split(' ') : [str];
  return arr[0];
}));

console.log(calendar_array);
```

#### Note:

- When your bottom script is mofidied, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  /**
  *@customfunction
  *@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
  *VERSION 1 - Returns ONLY the FIRST WORD in the array element to that array element
  */
  function firstWordArray(parameterArray) {
    calendarArray = parameterArray;
    for (week = calendarArray.length - 1; week >= 0; week--) {
      for (day = calendarArray[0].length - 1; day >= 0; day--) {
        let firstWord = calendarArray[week][day];
        if (firstWord instanceof String || typeof firstWord == "string") {
          firstWord = firstWord.split(' ');
          calendarArray[week][day] = firstWord[0];
        }
      }
    }
    return calendarArray;
  }
  ```

#### References

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)
- [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
function firstColumnElements() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [h,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let o = vs.map(r => [r[0]]);
  o.unshift(['First Column Elements']);
  osh.clear();
  osh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o)
}
```

Data:
Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 21 | 22 | 19 | 5 |
| 24 | 21 | 9 | 22 | 3 |
| 17 | 16 | 6 | 19 | 17 |
| 3 | 18 | 8 | 10 | 14 |
| 0 | 18 | 13 | 22 | 16 |
| 24 | 12 | 0 | 19 | 10 |
| 21 | 23 | 13 | 18 | 10 |
| 12 | 11 | 23 | 9 | 5 |
| 20 | 7 | 16 | 12 | 13 |

Output:
Sheet1:
First Column Data Elements

| First Column Elements |
| --- |
| 9 |
| 24 |
| 17 |
| 3 |
| 0 |
| 24 |
| 21 |
| 12 |
| 20 |

Answer (score 0):

This appears to the intermittent caching issue when it comes to GAS custom functions.